# Jquery UI Combobox wont trigger on change if empty

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

i have a JQuery UI Combobox. I use it as a filter.
I got an on change event, i select something from the combobox and then the site reloads with the new filtered data, this is ok its what i want. The problem is if i leave it empty or delete the filed it it wont call the on change event. This is a problem cause once filtered , it cant be set back to the non filtered data. I tried other events (keyup, keydown, click...) non is working. Any idea?

there is not much to see:

```
    $('#campaign_id').change(function(){
        console.log('test');
    } );
```

the problem is on change wont trigger if field is empty.

This is inside my framework if it helps:

```
            $output .= nl().'<script type="text/javascript"><!--';
                $output .= nl().'   $(function() {';
                $output .= nl().'       $("#'.$this->getName(true).'").combobox({';
                $output .= nl().'           selected: function() {$(this).change();}';
                $output .= nl().'       });';
```

Comment: Plz show us your code, it is the only way we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
$('.ui-combobox-input').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $('#campaign_id').val('');
        reloadForm();
    }
})
```